# Unable to show "Today" in place of Today Date

Tags: html, angular

I am working on weather application where I want to show Current week weather detail and I am getting all data from server.

but what I want is on Today and Tomorrow date I want to show "**Today**" & "**Tomorrow**" text.

UI:

[image]

I have done below logic but unable to get it done.

I am comparing today date with server provided date and if both are same I will show "**Today**" string.

**.ts**

```
this.today = new Date();
this.dateString = this.today.toString()
```

**HTML**

```
 <th colspan="2" class="thStyle">{{ item.applicable_date === dateString ? "Today" : "Today" }}</th>
```

Comment: Have you consoled both item.applicable_date and dateString ??.Is that string contains same date (especially format)??

Comment: no actually both format are different

Comment: can you show your date format that comes from server

Comment: yyyy-MM-dd formate from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conver the date to the particular format

```
this.dateString = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: above code is working perfectly but what about tomorrow how can I add 1 day in today date ?

Comment: just use date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

Comment: getting conversion error `[ts] Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date'.`

Comment: let today=new Date();let tomorrow=new Date(today.getTime()+24*60*60*1000);let todayString=today.toISOString().slice(0,10);let tomorrowString=tomorrow.toISOString().slice(0,10)